# Executing .jar files with a double click

Tags: java, executable-jar, double-click

I've been using Eclipse as my Java IDE and today I ran into an interesting problem.  I used the built in file>export>runnable jar file to create a jar file for one of my programs.  It runs perfectly if I start it from the command line/with a batch file, but doesn't run from a double click.  I made absolutely certain that .jar files are associated with javaw and it still didn't work.  It isn't a huge problem I absolutely NEED fixed, but if anyone has any ideas I'd love to hear them.

Update:  I tried using Aram Kocharyan's solution (see answer below).  No luck.  It seems to be just this one .jar file too.  All other jars launch with a double click. Rebuilding the jar doesn't help. :P

Comment: Anything happens when you double click on the jar ? Also what should normally happen when you run it from command line ?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a short guide on this a while back you might find helpful:

http://ak.net84.net/projects/how-to-make-a-multi-platform-executable-java-jar-file/

This will work on double click in windows without setting any additional settings, and I've tested it with the Jar Launcher on Mac and it doesn't complain.

Comment: Here's something interesting.  I tested your guide, at least the second half, because the first half was essentially what I have already done.  The application created by exej won't run with a double click, but a batch file with the command `java -jar JarFile.jar` will.

Comment: No luck :(  I just don't get it.  I've even used this GUI successfully before in other projects.  I've even tried commenting out everything except the GUI initialization and rebuilding.  Eclipse just hates my project for some reason.

Comment: Have you tried creating a simple "Hello World" program and testing that?

Comment: Yeah. Any other jar file I build works fine. But rebuilding, or even moving to a separate eclipse project doesn't work

Comment: Try to compare the `.*` (eg. `.settings`) or whatever file eclipse makes with a blank project and see if you have any differences. Then make a jar and launch it in the command line - see if any errors come up. It might be a missing class file it can't find due to the paths etc. Notice that any resources I had needed to be sitting beside the exe and jar.

Comment: This link is broken now

Answer (score 0):

open your jar with..`javaw`
which is in bin folder of jre... in my computer it is @

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre\bin\javaw.exe
```

Answer (score -1):

Put this inside a .bat:

```
start javaw -classpath "%~dp0YOU-JAR-NAME.jar" -Djava.library.path="native" foo.package.bar.YourClassWithMainMethod
```

the option `-Djava.library.path="native"` its not required for run, i include this because one reason for using a .bat instead do a double click on a .jar is to use JVM-parameters, in my case i need this parameter for my project run.

the %~dp0 part get current directory